# Loop over soft-wrapped visual lines

Tags: emacs

I have a function that I want to apply in a loop over visual lines rather than only hard-wrapped lines. How can I iterate over visual lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but you can use `next-line` with non-nil `line-move-visual`, `beginning-of-visual-line`, and `end-of-visual-line`.

Example:

```
(defun foo (&optional start end)
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (or start (point-min)))
        (end (or end (point-max)))
        b e)
    (goto-char start)
    (while (<= (point) end)
      (beginning-of-visual-line)
      (setq b (point))
      (save-excursion 
        (end-of-visual-line)
        (setq e (point)))
      (message "%d %d" b e)
      (let ((line-move-visual t))
        (next-line)))))
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Perhaps a descriptive function name (or docstring) might help future readers : )